# Many-Many Relationship in GDAL Pixel Functions

Tags: raster, gdal, vrt

I am using pixel functions (in Python) in VRT derived data sets. As far as I know it is only possible to use One-One or Many-One relationships within a pixel function. In other words, the `in_ar` includes one raster or multiple, whereas `out_ar` is flat, i.e. it should be a 2D array.

Is it somehow possible to save multiple output bands or is there a workaround?

As an example: I want to sort values of the 3D input array along the third dimension and then store each layer/level to a new output bands.